# Problems with large bool on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to get all documents that contain at least one item from a list of more than 1024.

My query is basically a **bool query** with a **should** and **minimum_should_match: 1**.

Elasticsearch maxClauseCount is set to 1024 by default. I have tried to set it to 4096 and the configuration looks to be ok:

I request http://myserver:9200/my_index/_settings and get:

`...
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "max_clause_count": "4096"
  }
}
...,`

But if I try still get `TooManyClauses[maxClauseCount is set to 1024]` in my logs.

**1st Question:** Why is this contradictory?

I have read that for some cases it is better to use a filter instead of a large bool:

> In general I'd recommend to rewrite that query to use terms filter instead of boolean query
>   https://discuss.elastic.co/t/too-many-clauses-maxclausecount-is-set-to-1024/61968

**2nd Question:** How could I use a filter to obtain the same logic as the multiple should bool on my example? What is best bool filter or filtered filter for that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not yet sure why Elasticsearch raise the maxClauseCount error, but i have found an alternative way to structure my query.

The (easy) solution is to use terms with the large list of items. If I use it into a `must` I get the same error, but with `filter` it works perfectly.

Example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"terms": {"my_field": ["item1", "item2", ... "itemN"]}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The only lack for `filter` is that:

> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike must the score of the query will be ignored.
>   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html